# Why is the compiler giving a warning that a pointer may be uninitialized when it's going to be initialized and won't the pointer update?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

```c
    char *s, *p = s;
    size_t len = 0;

    while (str[len++]);

    s = malloc(sizeof(*s) * (len + 1));
```

How come here: `char *s, *p = s;` gives warning, but `s` is going to be initialized with `malloc` later.

```
chl/string.c:9:15: warning: ‘s’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
    9 |     char *s, *p = s;
                      ^
```

Since `p` is a pointer, pointing to s, won't `p` be updated as well when it points to `s` when `s` will be memory allocated?

Why would I have to do this instead:

```c
    char *s, *p;
    size_t len = 0;

    while (str[len++]);

    s = malloc(sizeof(*s) * (len + 1));
    p = s;
```

I thought pointers can change to what it points to, so why isn't `p` being updated as a pointer? Or if I'm seeing this wrong, why can't I just do `*p = s`, because `s` soon is going to be initialized, and `p` will point to `s`, so won't `p` update too?

Comment: `*p = s` puts the current value of s in p.  s is undefined.

Comment: `p` isn't pointing to `s`.  That would require `char **p = &s;` . An assignment  `x = y;` copies the value of `y` to `x`, it doesn't make `x` refer to the location of `y` or anything

Comment: But can't the value of the pointer pointing to can change? Like `*s` was undefined, but now since I assigned `malloc`, the pointer changed and now points to malloc.

Comment: p doesn't point to s.  If you do `a = b` a doesn't change if you change b later.

Comment: @stark Yeah, though pointers.. `int a = 3; int *b = &a; a = 5; printf("%d\n", *b);` since `a` changed to `5`, b still points to `a`, but `b` will be now 5 when dereferenced because `a` changed.

Comment: @JackMurrow see how you wrote `&a` and `*b` there , unlike in that code in your question. If you try `int a = 3; int b = a; a = 5; printf("%d\n", b);` you get `3`

Comment: @M.M Wait, then how come for example `*p++ = 'e'` will also change `s`, if it doesn't refer to the same location? Because it points to the first element?

Comment: `*p++ = 'e';` does not change `s`.

Comment: Yes but it does change `s[0]`

Comment: yes, and `s[0]` is not `s`. It is a different memory location that `s` holds the address of.  You seem to be confusing pointers with the memory locations they point to.

Comment: so the memory block of `s` is copied to `p` but it's still the same memory block?

Comment: not clear what you mean by "the memory block of s"  , such terminology still indicates confusing pointers with where they point.  `s` is in a memory location (as is every variable), and it stores the address of another memory location .

Comment: @M.M The memory block, when you call `malloc`, it returns a memory block doesn't it?

Comment: Yes. You can make `s` and `p` both point to the same memory block. That is what `p = s;` does.   If you execute `p = s;` before `s` points to any memory block, you just have two pointers that are not pointing to any memory block.

Comment: @JackMurrow: "*when you call `malloc`, it returns a memory block doesn't it?*": no, in a statement like `char * s = malloc(...)` the function call to `malloc()` returns the *address of* a block of memory, which in fact becomes the value of the pointer `s`.

Comment: How come, `char *s = malloc(100); char *p = s;`, `p` doesn't actually point to `s`, but technically if I did this `p[0] = 'e'`, it will also do that to `s` (changing `s[0]` as well), so how come changing `p` by index changes `s` by index as well even though technically `p` doesn't point to `s`?

Answer (score 8):

Let's break this down a little.

What you have essentially is this:

```
char *s;
char *p = s;
s = malloc(...);
```

You're proposing that when `s` gets initialized (by `malloc`'s return value), the value of `p` should also update.

But, as you've discovered this is not the case. Initially, when you do `char *s`, `s` can point to *anything*. It is not yet initialized.

Subsequently, when you do `char *p = s;`, you are assigning the **current** value of `s` to `p` -- which could be *anything*.

If you *change* the value of `s`, that doesn't automatically change the value of `p`. They are **distinct** variables. They are both pointers - but that doesn't mean they should point to the same thing just because one was initialized from the other.

There is no intrinsic link between these two pointers, even if you assign one to the other. The point is, even if they do point to the same thing at one point in time, you can change what one points to in the future without affecting the other.

Its actually no different from assigning to a non-pointer variable and asserting that it should be updated automatically, e.g.

```
int i;
int j;
i = j;
j = 5;
printf("%d\n", i); // Prints rubbish
printf("%d\n", j); // Prints 5
```

Here, `j` is initialized and the `printf` is as expected. Meanwhile, `i` was initialized from `j`'s rubbish value -- the value that happened to be lying in memory at `j`'s location (and that could be *anything*). Yet, I doubt anyone would suggest that `i` should "automatically" update in this case.

**UPDATE:**

The following update is in response to this followup comment made:

> Here's why I thought it would update.. char *s =  malloc(100); char *p
> = s; see this, right? p[0] = 'e' for example will also change s[0], so I thought that since if assigning the element of p by index would also
> change the element of s by index, there would be change/update, right?
> How come p[0] = 'e' changes the element of both s and p, even though p
> just assigned the current value of malloc? They are different pointers
> but point to the same memory block, that's why! Am I right?

In this example, `p` and `s` again point to the same memory. When you do the assignment `p[0] = 'e'`, you are **NOT** changing `p` or `s` -- you are in fact changing the value pointed to by `p`. And, since `p` and `s` point to the same memory, the change you've made will be visible through both `p` and `s` -- when you dereference either. Below is an in-depth example - I recommend compiling it and running it to see what gets printed, and read the comments which explain what is happening at each step.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    // this initializes s to point to some block of memory, e.g. address 0x560890f49260 when I run it locally
    // it can store 100 bytes (chars) of data
    char *s = malloc(100);

    // this initializes p to point to the same block of memory as s => 0x560890f49260
    char *p = s;

    // this prints out the value of p and s
    // they are of type 'pointer', so use %p
    // this shows their address as being the same
    printf("This is where p points to: %p\n", p);
    printf("This is where s points to: %p\n", s);

    // this sets the 1st byte at the location pointed to by p
    // the thing we're changing is at address 0x560890f49260
    // this "array" notation is just syntactic sugar for dereferencing a pointer - see below
    p[0] = 'e';

    // but p and s are unchanged
    printf("This is where p points to: %p\n", p);
    printf("This is where s points to: %p\n", s);

    // this also changes the 1st byte (same as *p = 'e' and p[0] = 'e')
    // here we're using the dereferencing syntax explictly
    *(p + 0) = 'e';

    // and p and s are still the same
    printf("This is where p points to: %p\n", p);
    printf("This is where s points to: %p\n", s);

    // this changes the 2nd byte (same as p[1] = 'f')
    // the thing we're changing is at address 0x560890f49261 - i.e. the next byte
    *(p + 1) = 'f';

    // and p and s still haven't changed
    printf("This is where p points to: %p\n", p);
    printf("This is where s points to: %p\n", s);

    // this prints the 1st and 2nd byte pointed to by p and s
    // they show the same thing in both cases - since p and s point to the same thing
    printf("First byte pointed to by p: %c\n", p[0]);
    printf("First byte pointed to by s: %c\n", s[0]);
    printf("Second byte pointed to by p: %c\n", p[1]);
    printf("Second byte pointed to by s: %c\n", s[1]);

    // now p is pointing to something new, e.g. address 0x5617ba3ef6e0 when I run it locally
    p = malloc(100);

    // we see that p **HAS** changed, but s has **NOT** changed
    // they are now pointing to different things
    printf("This is where p points to: %p (new location!)\n", p);
    printf("This is where s points to: %p (old location!)\n", s);

    // this sets the 1st byte pointed to by p to be 'g'
    p[0] = 'g';

    // we can see that the 1st byte pointed to by p is 'g'
    printf("First byte pointed to by p: %c\n", p[0]);

    // while the first byte pointed to be s is unaffected
    // since p and s point to different things
    printf("First byte pointed to by s: %c\n", s[0]);

    // always free your memory
    free(p);
    free(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here's why I thought it would update.. `char *s =  malloc(100); char *p = s;` see this, right? `p[0] = 'e'` for example will also change `s[0]`, so I thought that since if assigning the element of `p` by index would also change the element of `s` by index, there would be change/update, right? How come `p[0] = 'e'` changes the element of both `s` and `p`, even though `p` just assigned the **current** value of malloc? They are different pointers, but point to the same memory block (`malloc`), that's why! Am I right? So `p` doesn't **point** to `s`, but it points to the `malloc` of `s`?

Comment: See my update in response to this followup comment.

Answer (score 3):

Oh no, p is not pointing to s.

Your statement:

```
char *p = s;
```

It's saying "copy the value of pointer s, into pointer p", so whatever may be the address stored in s (which is not initialized) it's what's going to be the value stored in p.

Once s is assigned the value of the malloc, p will remain with the initial value and s will be different.